# How do I add a NSNumber fetched object from Parse to a NSMutable array?

Tags: parse-platform, nsmutablearray, nsnumber

I have a normal Parse query and inside the query i have this piece of code that basically fetched all objects found:

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // The find succeeded.
            NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %lu scores.", (unsigned long)objects.count);
            // Do something with the found objects


            for (NSObject *object in objects){

                NSLog(@"vacants %d ", [[object valueForKey:@"Vacants"]intValue]);
                [eventnameArray addObject:[object valueForKey:@"EventName"]];
                [userArray addObject:[object valueForKey:@"Username"]];
                [sportArray addObject:[object valueForKey:@"Sportname"]];
                [hourArray addObject:[object valueForKey:@"Hour"]];
                [dateArray addObject:[object valueForKey:@"Date"]];
                [placeArray addObject:[object valueForKey:@"Place"]];
                [vacantsArray addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt:[object valueForKey:@"Vacants"]]];
                [cityArray addObject:[object valueForKey:@"City"]];

            }




        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }

        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];
```

For Vacantsarray the fetched value from the Parse Cloud in a number. I cannot seem to be able to add this numeric value to the NSMutablearray

It throws me this error:

```
-[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

EDIT :

Doing this:

```
[vacantsArray addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:[object valueForKey:@"Vacants"]]];
```

throws me this error:

```
-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NSString stringWithFormat to convert NSNumber before perform any operations like isEqualToString.

Comment: Could the add object be expecting a String?

Comment: Check it"s Class and see what kind of is.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it by doing this :

```
[vacantsArray addObject: [(NSNumber*)[object valueForKey:@"Vacants"] stringValue]];
```